# Random empty files called "file*" are created on /tmp

Tags: linux, redhat, unix, filesystems

I have two RHEL 6.10 servers where /tmp is constantly being filled up with thousands of files with the following names

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:30 fileoQ1gE0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:31 fileTFa0e7
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:32 fileSxEdEa
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:33 filegoLf6g
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:34 filebj3CJv
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:35 fileEVJerA
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:36 file5X9G3G
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:37 fileScyBJY
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:38 filePCq3K0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:39 filePnBcVp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:40 fileTbupIR
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:41 file4jmFGS
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:42 fileBP8HL0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:43 fileb605If
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:44 file8Rubgm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:45 file7UJEJr
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:46 filethKoZv
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:47 fileJEVJpL
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:48 filebeLOuP
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:49 fileN1VVJU
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:50 fileHO9fll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:51 filejEj1Rq
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root    root        0 Feb 22 17:52 fileMPnCWJ
```

Root's crontab doesn't have anything so, is there any way to know what process is creating files here? Even though they're 0 bytes it is bothering me since I just don't know why they're created.

Comment: Looks like one is created each minute. Knowing the times with a bit more accuracy could provide some indication of whether it is likely to be a cron job. You can see the full timestamp with `ls --full-time /tmp`. I'd also take a look in `/var/log/cron` to know if any cron job is being run every minute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable `auditd` and write some rules watching write-type permissions to this directory.

```
-w /tmp -p w -k tmp
```

[How to monitor permission, ownership or any other change to a particular directory or file](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10107)

[RHEL 6 Security Guide > Chapter 7. System Auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing)

Comment: This helped me to pinpoint the issue and ausearch returns the following, yet I'm unable to understand why that process is creating files:


`id=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=87305 comm="osspi_fwtmp" exe="/var/opt/OV/bin/instrumentation/osspi_fwtmp" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="tmp"`
_
`type=PATH msg=audit(1551283056.129:18464144): item=1 name="/tmp/fileHjArsp" inode=2735 dev=fd:04 mode=0100664 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 nametype=CREATE`

Comment: The briefest of searches suggests this is OpenView. Why it doesn't clean up after itself is a question for this products support channels, and digging through its source code where available. Common uses of `mkstemp` style temporary files are to spool output going somewhere else, or to check that the temp dir is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a quick `lsof|grep /tmp/file` spits out a PID the files belong to?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't hurt to try this. But you may need to be very lucky to catch it while the file is still open.